# Compiz not drawing window controls

Tags: compiz, window-manager, metacity

I have recently installed driver for my ATI graphic card in my Dell Studio laptop. I have also read this somewhere on the web that Ubuntu enables compiz window manager by default if your hardware can run it. Is it true ?

In my case before Installing graphic card driver the window manager was Metacity, but now I have compiz as my Window manager. I found this out uisng [Displex](http://sourceforge.net/projects/displex/) Indicator applet also confirmed by `wmctrl -m`.

From the time I have installed graphic card drivers, the window manager(Compiz) is not drawing window control buttons for some of the windows. For example if I open a terminal I have to close it using key board shortcuts or use the File -> Quit option in app-menu. Also I am not able to move the window because of this. From then when-ever I find a window without window control buttons I am restarting the window manager using Displex Indicator applet. But this is very annoying and also consumes a lot of time(when I am doing my work).

Can any one suggest any solution for this.

What are up's and down's of using Compiz Vs Metacity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had a similar problem recently. My ktorrent, Amarok and few other applications just wouldn't draw any controls.. kind of like default(and irreversible) full-screen. I played around with CCSM and on disabling Utility->Workaroound and restarting the failing applications solved the problem. I'll still go ahead and check which feature in the plugin in particular causes the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I think some of your **CCSM**'s*(Compiz config settings manager)* plug ins are working bad or something, go to CCSM and click on the Radio button of the Windows Decoration to turn it off and click again to turn it on,it will help.(if it does not work try to do the same thing to other plugins too, rarely those plugins fail to load correctly and give some extra SLOW to the pc) You can move windows without the need of the title bar, just grab alt and click on the window and move :-)