# Unity Window Drawing Issue after Upgrade to 16.10

Tags: unity, upgrade, nautilus

I recently upgraded to Ubuntu (Unity) 16.10 from 16.04.  Now, I did screw the pooch during the upgrade by shutting my laptop and causing a mid-upgrade suspend.  But I was able to use single-user login to fix the messed package upgrade via terminal.

I say that only for background.  My issue is that certain windows are not drawing entirely correctly.  See the attached pictures of Dconf Editor and Speedcrunch.

[image: Dconf Editor]
[image]

Also, I can't get icons to appear on contextual menus (whereas they did work in 16.04), and the icons for Nautilus appear just a little too small.

[image]

Based on [this link](https://askubuntu.com/questions/112493/compiz-not-drawing-window-controls), I am thinking the issue is with CCSM, as during the upgrade all of my CCSM settings were erased.  But I tried the two suggestions in the link to no avail.

Any ideas?